# "Multiple definition of" error while writing a header-only template library

Tags: c++, header-only

My project resembles this set up, when I need to use `my_template_library.h` in `main_class.h`.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "main_class.h"

int main()
{
    MainClass m;
    return m.exec();
}
```

**main_class.h**

```
#ifndef MAIN_CLASS_H
#define MAIN_CLASS_H

#include "my_template_library.h"

class MainClass {
public:
    MainClass();
    int exec();
};

#endif // MAIN_CLASS_H
```

**main_class.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "main_class.h"

MainClass::MainClass(){}

int MainClass::exec()
{
    std::cout << "exec!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**my_template_library.h**

```
#ifndef MY_TEMPLATE_LIBRARY_H
#define MY_TEMPLATE_LIBRARY_H

#include <iostream>

//#pragma message ("I'm being included past the include guards!")

class MyTemplateLibrary
{
public:
    MyTemplateLibrary();

    void function();
};

MyTemplateLibrary::MyTemplateLibrary(){}

void MyTemplateLibrary::function()
{
    std::cout << "function called!" << std::endl;
}

#endif // MY_TEMPLATE_LIBRARY_H
```

In the template header-only library I write I first declare everything in a class and then define everything outside the class, like what you would usually do when you separate your class into `.h` and `.cpp` code, but with `.cpp` file added at the end of `.h`, inside include guards. This worked fine as long as my template library was included only once, but when it started to be included more than that I got some very confusing issues.

```
$ g++ -o test main.cpp main_class.h main_class.cpp my_template_library.h 
/tmp/ccuFlEDZ.o: In function `MyTemplateLibrary::MyTemplateLibrary()':
main_class.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `MyTemplateLibrary::MyTemplateLibrary()'
/tmp/ccZikorv.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccuFlEDZ.o: In function `MyTemplateLibrary::MyTemplateLibrary()':
main_class.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `MyTemplateLibrary::MyTemplateLibrary()'
/tmp/ccZikorv.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccuFlEDZ.o: In function `MyTemplateLibrary::function()':
main_class.cpp:(.text+0xa): multiple definition of `MyTemplateLibrary::function()'
/tmp/ccZikorv.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xa): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm confused as to what is going on. I have added the `#pragma message` to my_template_library.h to make some sense out of this, which you see here commented out in the code. When I uncomment it and run the code I get

```
$ g++ -o test main.cpp main_class.h main_class.cpp my_template_library.h 
In file included from main_class.h:4:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
my_template_library.h:6:63: note: #pragma message: I'm being included past the include guards!
 #pragma message ("I'm being included past the include guards!")
                                                           ^
In file included from main_class.h:4:0:
my_template_library.h:6:63: note: #pragma message: I'm being included past the include guards!
 #pragma message ("I'm being included past the include guards!")
                                                           ^
In file included from main_class.h:4:0,
             from main_class.cpp:3:
my_template_library.h:6:63: note: #pragma message: I'm being included past the include guards!
 #pragma message ("I'm being included past the include guards!")
                                                           ^
my_template_library.h:6:63: note: #pragma message: I'm being included past the include guards!
 #pragma message ("I'm being included past the include guards!")
                                                           ^
/tmp/ccmawdhP.o: In function `MyTemplateLibrary::MyTemplateLibrary()':
main_class.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `MyTemplateLibrary::MyTemplateLibrary()'
/tmp/cc4XSnui.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccmawdhP.o: In function `MyTemplateLibrary::MyTemplateLibrary()':
main_class.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `MyTemplateLibrary::MyTemplateLibrary()'
/tmp/cc4XSnui.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccmawdhP.o: In function `MyTemplateLibrary::function()':
main_class.cpp:(.text+0xa): multiple definition of `MyTemplateLibrary::function()'
/tmp/cc4XSnui.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xa): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So the header file is being included through:

1. main.cpp -> main_class.h
2. main_class.h
3. main_class.cpp -> main_class.h
4. my_template_library.h (by itself?)

So, my questions are:

1. Why include guards don't help?
2. How to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Your template library does not appear to consist of templates.

Comment: You need to put your function bodies in the source file, unless they are inline or templates.

Comment: It's just a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can imagine there are some templates in MyTemplateLibrary class. Removed the "Template" tag.

Comment: Include guards do nothing to stop multiple definitions across translation units.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why include guards don't help?

Include guards prevent redundant code within the **same** compilation unit.

You are getting a linker error about **different** compilation units claiming to hold the same function definition.

> How to prevent this from happening?

You need to make those non-template member functions `inline` to avoid violating the [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

One way is to explicitly declare them inline.

```
inline MyTemplateLibrary::MyTemplateLibrary(){}
```

Alternately, functions defined within the class definition are implicitly inline.

```
class MyTemplateLibrary
{
public:
    MyTemplateLibrary() {}

    void function()
    {
        std::cout << "function called!" << std::endl;
    }
};
```